# UITableView doesn't show bars to move the cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I tried to implement this method in order to be able to move the cells in my Tableview.
And everything runs well but the bars aren't shown and I'm not able to move the cells.

```
- (void)moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {


[[HPPossessionStore defaultStore] movePossessionAtIndex:[indexPath row] toIndex:[newIndexPath row]];

}
```

What do I have to do to make it work?

Comment: Please check the other SO questions before asking such questions, You may get demoted.

Comment: Replacing the method solved my problem, although I have no idea why. If someone could explain it I would be very thankful.

    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
    {
     [[HPPossessionStore defaultStore] movePossessionAtIndex:[fromIndexPath row] toIndex:[toIndexPath row]];
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add below delegate method as well.

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem, although I have no idea why. If someone could explain it I would be very thankful.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
 [[HPPossessionStore defaultStore] movePossessionAtIndex:[fromIndexPath row] toIndex:[toIndexPath row]];
}
```

It is explained in more detail here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20786785/2310837